# "Toi, toi, toi" – was genau bedeutet dieser Ausdruck?

Tags: meaning, expression, idiom

Ich habe gerade "Toi, toi, toi" gehört, und habe keine Ahnung, wie ich das nehmen sollte! Ist es gut? Schlecht?

Wenn man im Englischen "Tut, tut, tut..." hört, es ist nicht so prickelnd. Hat dieser Ausdruck mit etwas Anderem zu tun?

Comment: Es gibt die Vermutung, daß der Ausdruck aus dem Jiddischen kommt. Siehe dazu den folgenden [Artikel](http://www.juedische-allgemeine.de/article/view/id/24982).

Comment: Interessant, wie sich der [deutsche](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toi,_toi,_toi) vom [englischen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toi_toi_toi) Wikipedia-Artikel unterscheidet!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Der Begriff "Toi, toi, toi" ist eine onomatopoetische Umschreibung des Brauchs "dreimal über die Schulter spucken". Dies ist ein abergläubischer Brauch, der besonders von Schauspielern verwendet wird, um sich gegenseitig Glück zu wünschen, bevor sie auf die Bühne treten und die Vorstellung beginnen.

Im Aberglauben verhaftet, ist es tabu, sich vor der ersten Vorstellung "Viel Glück" zu wünschen. Das würde nur Unglück bringen, z. B. verpatzte Szenen, vergessenen Text etc. Stattdessen umarmt man den Gegenüber und "spuckt" ihm/ihr sinnbildlich dreimal über die linke Schulter, was mit der Äußerung "Toi, toi, toi" verbalisiert wird. In Wirklichkeit wird nicht "toi, toi, toi" gesagt, sondern ein Spuck-Geräusch nachgeahmt. Es klingt es eher wie "Tü, tü, tü" (ganz schnell gesprochen).

Der Aberglaube besagt, dass der Wunsch "Viel Glück" eher Unglück bringt. Parallelen dazu finden sich bei anderen Aktivitäten, z. B. "Hals und Beinbruch" in manchen Sportarten, wo auch kein direkter Wunsch zum Erfolg ausgedrückt wird.

Ich habe dafür keine Quellen, aber reichlich Bühnenerfahrung. Meine Schulter ist immer noch nicht ganz getrocknet von dem ganzen Tü-tü-tü.

Comment: "Hals und Beinbruch" ist kein gutes Beispiel, das kommt nämlich aus dem jiddischen und bedeutet exakt "Viel Glück": http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hals-_und_Beinbruch

Comment: Danke, ladybug, +1 -- das war mir nicht bekannt.

Comment: Ladybug +1, ist ja kränk. Wieder eine Wette, die ich verloren hätte.

Comment: Es soll genauso Unglück bringen auf ein "Toi, toi, toi" zu antworten, womöglich sich für den Wunsch zu bedanken.

Answer (score 24):

Der Ausspruch "toi, toi, toi" ist ein Glückwunsch im Sinne von "Es möge gelingen!".

Er soll entstanden sein, um das Ausspucken, das seit dem 18. Jahrhundert als unanständig empfunden wurde, zu ersetzen.

[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toi,_toi,_toi):

> [toi toi toi] beruht auf einem Abwehrzauber gegen den Neid böser Geister. Um sie durch einen Glückwunsch nicht herbeizurufen, war es üblich, die Formel „unberufen“ hinzuzufügen und durch dreimaliges Ausspucken[1](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toi,_toi,_toi), Klopfen auf Holz oder ähnliche Handlungen die Schutzwirkung zu bekräftigen.
>
> Der Ausspruch „toi, toi, toi“ entstand als lautmalerischer Ersatz für das Ausspucken, das seit dem 18. Jahrhundert zunehmend als unanständig empfunden wurde. Auch heute noch wird er gelegentlich durch ein „unberufen“ und Klopfen auf Holz begleitet.

Comment: I do like the "Teufel unberufen" explanation as well, although it sounds a bit like "Etymogelei" ^^

Comment: Ich meine, man spuckte früher drei Mal über die Schulter des "Opfers", dem man -es umarmend- Glück wünschte. So gesehen ist "toi toi toi" das antike Gegenstück zum Internet-Mem "Nom nom nom" :-)

Answer (score 18):

"Toi, toi, toi" heißt für mich eigentlich nur so viel wie "Viel Glück" oder auch "Hoffentlich geht das gut". Je nach Kontext.

> A: Ich habe gleich mündliche Prüfung!
>   B: Na dann mal toi, toi, toi.

oder

> A: Klar, die Leiter wird das schon aushalten.
>   B: Toi, toi, toi...

Answer (score 8):

Wenn man "Toi, toi, toi" ausruft, wünscht man seinem Gegenüber Glück. Man könnte es mit *knock on wood* übersetzen.

Ürsprünglich wurde dieser (abergläubische) Ausspruch verwendet, um böse Geister abzuwenden.

Comment: *Man könnte es mit knock on wood übersetzen* Ja und viele klopfen dabei auch tatsächlich auf Holz. (*schauder*)

Comment: Es gibt ja auch die Redewendung "Dreimal auf Holz geklopft.".

Comment: @musiKk: Das kürzere "Klopf auf Holz" hab ich auch schon öfter gehört.

Answer (score 7):

"Toi, toi, toi" heißt, "ich wünsche Dir Glück".

---

It's a term of encouragement. Basically the person was wishing you good luck. Related idioms include:

> - Hals- und Beinbruch! (≈ "break a leg")
> - Ich drücke Dir die Daumen! (≈ "I will keep my fingers crossed for you")

Comment: Break a leg, arg! Please see my comment on teylyn answer. ^^

Comment: @ladybug: I don't understand. You do realize that *break a leg* [is an idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_a_leg) with the exact same meaning, "Good luck"?

Comment: Oh, no, I didn't! Thought it was intended as tranlation. That's actually pretty interesting, might even explain why someone would turn the Yiddish wish into "Hals and Beinbruch"...? Edit: not the first one who thought this, but other way round: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_a_leg#Yiddish_origin

Answer (score 4):

Was noch nicht eindeutig geklärt wurde, war die zweite Frage im Bezug auf "Tut tut tut …":
Während "Toi, toi, toi" ein Ausdruck ist, der quasi "Viel Glück" oder "Ich drück dir die Daumen" bedeutet, ist das englische "Tut, tut, tut …" eine Weise, Missfallen auszudrücken.

> Tut tut tut, Robin, you disappoint me.

Auch wenn es von der Form ähnlich ist, ist es von der Bedeutung her nicht vergleichbar.